# dojo.io.script.get vs dojo.xhrGet

Tags: ajax, dojo, jsonp

I have spent days working on this and really feel dumb. I have been working on demos and samples that never work when I try it locally with my own url. I have a web service that returns results back in json and am just basically trying to call it using dojo and for now just view the results. I took the search google example and just substituted the url and parameters. Now perhaps I still do not understand the basics so: 
  - io.script.get vs xhrGet
if using cross domain urls it is better to use io.script.get? correct?
now what is the callbackparam? is this the function that is being called in the webservice?
My webservice url is as follows:
http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/WcfServices/WcfInstance/Service1.svc/RetrievData?query=Word

when I use the following code I get nothing displayed.

```
function searchGoogle() {
    // Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
    var targetNode = dojo.byId("rules");

    // The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
    var jsonpArgs = {
        url: "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/WcfServices/WcfInstance/Service1.svc/RetrieveData?",
        callbackParamName: "callback",
        content: {

            query:"dojowords"
        },
        load: function (data) {
            // Set the data from the search into the viewbox in nicely formatted JSON
            targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.toJson(data, true) + "</pre>";
        },
        error: function (error) {
            targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
        }
    };
    dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
}
dojo.ready(searchGoogle);
```

Here is what the webservice results look like:

```
"{\"rules\":[{\"value\":\"AllState\"},
 {\"value\":\"Cidade de Goa beach\"},{\"value\":\"Euro 2012\"},     
 {\"value\":\"Euro2012\"},{\"value\":\"European&Championship\"},
 {\"value\":\"Holiday  Inn Resort\"},
 {\"value\":\"Holiday Inn Resort goa\"},
 {\"value\":\"Hotel Goa\"},{\"value\":\"Hyatt Goa\"},{\"value\":\"I buy car\"},...
```

If I get this part correct then at least I know I have data which I can then bind to a datagrid or chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dojo.io.script.get is for all cross domain requests.
xhrGet is for same domain requests.

dojo.io.script.get uses a hack which expects jsonp or json padding as a result. This wraps the response of the web service call inside a self executing function. The function name is the callback name. This has to be wired before the call so it knows what already defined function to call when a response comes back.

All of the arguments are well documented http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/io/script.html

My guess as to why your service isn't working is because you wrote the web service and it does not handle jsonp. It is not wrapping its response inside the callbackparamname.

your results should look something like

```
 callback({json});
```

where callback is whatever you set up in callbackParamName

you can also remove the ? from your url, that should be handled for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If the web application and webservice is hosted on the same server then I can use xhrGet? or will this be a problem when a client tries to run it from their machine but in our LAN. Secondly, would just wrapping my response like this callbackfunction({"{\"rules\":[{\"value\":\"AllState\"},
 {\"value\":\"Cidade de Goa beach\"},{\"value\":\"Euro 2012\"}]} work as far as the callback is concerned.

Comment: @vbNewbie there is no reason to use xhrGet if you are making a request from domain a to domain a. It doesn't matter that the client is distributed. As long as it is a -> a and not a -> b then xhrGet is fine. you will need to add handleAs: 'json' if you switch to dojo.xhrGet so read the reference guide. You can also make your service detect the callback parameter and decide whether to wrap the response or not to be flexible. I would not hard code the value. You get more capabilities using xhrGet also since it is supported and not a cros domain hack.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I do not wish to bombard you but when I did try dojo.xhrGet it kept telling my unable to load myurl. I ran it also from the same server and IE error was access denied. So one last question would be, will xhrGET be the best option for getting data from a remote server eg. a sql db to populate dojo widgets in a web application. I will do further research and sample from here on. Thanks again.

Comment: @vbNewbie just so you are aware, localhost != machine name != ip address. so for local dev, you can hit cross domain restrictions because of that. If x.domain.com requests anything from domain.com it is allowed. but as soon as you ask for domain2.com data it is denied. Get fiddler and look at what is happening. where your requests are originating from and going to. It is the best option if the remote server is on the same parent domain.

Comment: hey steve, thanks again for your responses; I opted to go with using JSONP and supporting in my web service. Just wanted to ask one more question - the callback parameter? How would I have my service detect the callback parameter? Is the callback function the function that handles the service call in the dojo application or what exactly is it? Basically I cannot ensure domain uniqueness so i have to get this io.script.get to work.

Comment: @vbNewbie you would have a mapped parameter in wcf called callback or whatever you wanted it to be. since wcf can model bind, you'd have to have a convention on what your callback function name would be so you can model bind. if the parameter in your method has a value then wrap the response, if it doesn't return vanilla json. there are tons of resources available with a search engine and I found this really quick : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898%28VS.90%29.aspx You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: This helped me pinpoint a stray reference to localhost in my code.  Thanks